# Excel - Find line containing specific values in matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-2016

**Hello there**

Let's say I have a matrix like the following :

```
    A   B   C

1   a | b | c
   ---|---|---
2   b | e | d
   ---|---|---
3   c | a | d
   ---|---|---
4   e | c | d
```

I am trying to find a formula to get the number of the line containing 3 specified letters. The order of these letters does not matter.
For exemple, if my input is `c, d, e`, the formula should return 4.
If it can help, in my matrix, each combination of letters is unique (you won't find a line `a | b | c` and then later a line `a | c | b`)
You can't have a letter repeated in a same line either (as in `a | a | b`).

The only solution I was able to make it work was to concatenate the three columns in another column, and then work on this fourth column, but I am really not satisfied with this solution.

The inputs can be hardcoded in the formula, I am only interested in the formula itself.

I am using Excel 2016.
Do you have something for me ?

Comment: Are your inputs in one cell or 3?  Is it always three columns?

Comment: @ScottCraner: In my case, it is always 3 columns yes. The inputs are a bit weird, there are 2 in one column and 1 in another column. But it's not a problem, you can consider they are in 3 columns, or even hardcode them in the formula. I'll add that to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & $A$1:$A$4 & ",","," & E1 & ",")))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & $B$1:$B$4& ",","," & E1 & ",")))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & $C$1:$C$4& ",","," & E1 & ",")))>0))
```

The drawback is each column will need to be added or removed to match the data.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand your formula to make it work in the context of my data. Instead of single letters, I have short strings. Is this important ? Could you explain why you concatenate "," to most of the strings ? I don't understand this part.

Comment: Whatever you use to split the strings, whether it is `,` or `, ` or `;` you need to append the exact delimitor to the front and back of both strings.  so that you do not get false positives.  for example `ann` would be found in `anne` and return a false postive.  so we add the `,` to the front and back and now `,ann,` is not found in `,anne,`

Comment: Oh ok, that's the separator. However, I don't manage to make it work... It seems to always return the same value (64 there, out of 84 rows).

Comment: make sure the separator is consistent; no space after the `,` or all need the space after the comma.

Comment: Yeah, I kept `,` as a separator, inputs do not contain any `,` of course, and there is no space in the search query. However all inputs are in brackets `[]`. I don't think this is relevant, but am I wrong ?

Comment: They need to match exactly what is in the columns, if the columns do not have brackets then the inputs cannot have them. or you have to add them to the deliminator.

Comment: Brackets are in the columns too. Here are more details about the context I'm working in : I have exactly 9 inputs possible, each one in brackets. I have generated all combinations of 3 inputs on 3 columns, without taking order in count, which makes 84 rows. And now I am trying to get the line of a combination by giving the 3 inputs of this combination. Is this information relevant ? Do you see something I could have missed using your formula ?

Comment: I think I found what's the problem... some inputs share the same letters, like [TEA] and [TEC] for instance. When I use inputs completely distincts, it seems to work, but as soon as I add this kind of input, it returns wrong values